# Boost serialization of vectors, crash in release build

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying basic Boost serialization examples. While trying to pass vectors I am facing an issue with this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

using namespace std;
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);

void save()
{
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);

  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back( 228 );
  v.push_back( 322 );

  oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(v);
}

void load()
{
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
  vector<int> tV;
  ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(tV) ;
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{    
    save();
    load();

   return 0;
}
```

**In release mode :** Program crashes without printing  the Hello message.

**In Debug mode   :** Program prints the Hello message and closes gracefully. I saw the value of vector tV in debug mode, it was showing the correctly filled values.

What is it that I might be doing wrong ?

P.S. : I did check similar problem on SO, but couldn't really relate to my issue.

---

**Edit as per comments:**

```
void save()
{
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);

  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back( 228 );
  v.push_back( 322 );

  oa << v;
}

void load()
{
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
  vector<int> ;
  ia >> v ;
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: is boost::serialization equipped to just handle a std::vector like that?

Comment: you should use BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP in both save and load, with same variable name.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk Thanks. I added that (and edited my post), but still the same crash. And what do you mean by `with same variable name` ?

Comment: @TonyTheLion Well, that what they [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-boostserialization/index.html?ca=drs-). Just that instead of using files, I am using stringstream. Can that be an issue ?

Comment: Like @EvgenyPanasyuk said - when using BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP both variables should have the same name (change `tV` to `v`). The macro uses BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE that converts the variables name to string used later for tag naming in XML. But you are using here `text_archive` so you can remove BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP in both functions

Comment: At which environment you have crash? Which boost version? Which compiler?

Comment: FWIW, it works ok under MSVC10, Win7, boost 1.53. (But you misuse BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP, as already was mentioned.)

Comment: @MaciekB I modified the code as per your suggestion, but exactly same behavior.

Comment: My guess is that you've got an ODR violation in release mode. Ensure that you build your program with exactly the same macros that serialization lib was built with. In particular, pay attention to _SECURE_SCL macro.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk I am using Ubuntu 10.10 - gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1) - Qt 4.8 - BOOST 1.53

Comment: The code, compiled by gcc 4.6.3, works without any crash. See the [link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/33ZJDX$6)

Comment: @IgorR. Ah! Crap.. I had an already installed version.. Not knowing that, I downloaded another version and gave paths to the corresponding new files.. Guess that is what was the problem, changed paths to the original folder, works like a charm.. If you could post your comment as an answer, I would like to accept it as the answer. You gave the direction I guess.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk Thanks. Got it working by linking to the proper lib

Comment: @Amit Tomar ok, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you've got an ODR violation in release mode.

Ensure that you build your program with exactly the same macros that `serialization` lib was built with. In particular, pay attention to `_SECURE_SCL` macro.